# LWUIT 1.4 : Internal error with Virtual Keyboard

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield, lwuit-vkb

When I click outside the `virtualKeyboard` when it is shown then I got a `Dialog` showing this message :

```
An internal application error occured : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Component is already contained in Container : 
Container[x=0 y=140 width=240 height=180, layout = BorderLayout, scrollableX = false, scrollableY = true, components = [VirtualKeyboard$1, Container]]
```

The error occured after showing more than once the `virtualKeyboard`.

I looked my code but I didn't find any word `BorderLayout` !

So how to correct this error ?

Comment: How to coloriate keywords when formatting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWUIT 1.4 is old and static version. So you can use new LWUIT version(1.5) or you can checkout the [LWUIT SVN repository](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show) and use latest updated version.